auf der Straße unterwegs sein
I have read/head the following sentence in tagesschau 20:00 Uhr, 27.08.2024 (7:30 m):

spoken text:

Die Polizei wurde gerufen, von Anwohnern, weil ein Mann hier auf der Straße wohl mit Messern unterwegs war, sie fühlten sich bedroht, daraufhin kam die Polizeistreife, entdecke den Mann hier in einer Nebenstraße, ...
 (The spoken sentence is much longer. The reporter adds more and more main clauses to it without lowering the voice at the end of these clauses while talking about the police shooting that man and his dead bady still laying in the street.) 


subtitles:

Anwohner haben die Polizei gerufen. Ein Mann war auf der Straße mit Messer unterwegs. Die Polizei kam und entdeckte den Mann in einer Nebenstraße. Er kam aus einem Haus mit Messern bewaffnet. ...



What does "unterwegs" mean in this context? I cannot match any of the meanings in https://www.wordreference.com/deen/unterwegs .
DeepL Translator ignores it when translating the sentence above:

A man was on the street with a knife.


Where exactly did you see or hear that? The sentence does not occur on that page, and the video is only 3min 34s lon, so your timestamp can't be correct?

A lot of details that are irrelevant to question have been added to my question (everything in parentheses and all the quoted text after "unterwegs war" / "unterwegs").

@AlanEvangelista: I'm not sure, whether your previous comment was intended as complaint. I personally find the question in pretty good shape as it currently is.

First of, the sentence must be

Ein Mann war auf der Straße mit einem Messer unterwegs.

otherwise it's not correct German.
Unterwegs literally means "on one's way", here in the sense of "walking around", but the meaning is broader. The word is commonly used in phrases like Der Mann ist unterwegs zur Arbeit (regardless of the means of transport he uses).
So, a better English translation of the above sentence would be

A man was walking (around) on the street with a knife.


Doesn't "unterwegs" literally mean "under ways" instead of "one one's way" ?

I am a native speaker and see no problem with mit Messer unterwegs.

@DavidVogt In the original post, the sentence was "Ein Mann war auf der Straße mit Messer unterwegs sein." Yes, the "einem" is optional, but it is still better style to use it, I think. Obviously except if it is "mit Messern" as in the spoken text.

I removed the "sein" word in "Ein Mann war auf der Straße mit Messer unterwegs sein" in the original post. It was a mistake. And thanks for noticing that the reporter said "Messern" (plural) instead of "Messer" (singular).

So "unterwegs" in the sentence here means "moving without a specific destination" ? That's the meaning of the intransitive "walk around" verb.

@AlanEvangelista Yes. As noted in my answer, you can also use it with a specific destination, but then you have to provide it explictly: "zur Arbeit", "zum Flughafen", etc.

Yes, "unterwegs" means without a specific destination, but it does not striclty mean that the man didn't know where to go but that in
the context of the news police/neighbors did not care nor know what this destination might have been, because it was (at that time) not relevant.

In this context, "unterwegs" means "to move without a specific destination" and it could be translated to the English verb "walk around". A better translation of the subtitled sentence (with the missing N at the end of "Messern" added)

Ein Mann war auf der Straße mit Messern unterwegs

would be:

A man was walking around on the street with knives.


I would challenge the without a specific destination part, not sure, if this has an impact on the translation.

@guidot The "without a specific destination" is what "around" means in the phrasal verb "to walk around". References: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/walk%20around , https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-translation/walk-around . I understood from PMF's answer that part was implied in "unterwegs" in the example sentence. Please let me know if that's not true.

In what manner was WordReference.com not useful? Click on the tab [WR reverse (23)]. There are 23 typical usages of unterwegs sein and the first two belong to the section Wichtigste Übersetzungen (most important translations). These most important translations are:

#1 underway; under way (moving) unterwegs
#2 abroad (outside of home) unterwegs = nicht zuhause

And #2 is exactly the meaning you are looking for.
The core meaning of unterwegs is: »on the way«, which is meant to describe a place and not a movement. The place where a person is located is an elongated and more or less flat surface called way and the person is located on it (the body is above it and the feet are touching it). Of course, if you are located on a way, then you are usually moving along that way, but that is neither the core meaning of English »on the way« nor of German »unterwegs«. The main meaning refers to the place.
But why does DeepL ignore unterwegs when it translates the German sentence into English?
Here is a complete translation:

Ger: Ein Mann war auf der Straße mit Messern unterwegs.
Eng: A man was on the way on the street with knives.

But in English the sequence on the way on the street contains two almost identical informations about the man's location. This is bad style, and DeepL always tries to provide something that a native speaker would have said in the same situation. And for that reason it eliminated one of both location details.

Additional information:
The subtitles do not really match the spoken text. They contain the same information, but in short sentences and with simplified grammar. Nevertheless, they contain an error (probably a typo). The sentence marked in bold in the question is grammatically incorrect:

Original sentence:

Ein Mann war auf der Straße mit Messer unterwegs.
A man was on the street with knife.


Two possible corrections:


Ein Mann war auf der Straße mit einem Messer unterwegs.
A man was on the street with a knife.
Ein Mann war auf der Straße mit Messern unterwegs.
A man was on the street with knives.




The speaker was talking all the time about a man with more than one knife (he used the plural form all the time), so version 2 is correct.

I do not understand why "on the way on the street" in English contains two almost identical pieces of information and is bad style, but the same does not apply to "auf der Straße unterwegs" in German, given that the meaning of "unterwegs" here is "outside home" and "outside home" and "on the street" are redundant. I can only guess that German is more tolerant to redundancy than English.

There is no redundancy. You can be "unterwegs mit der Bahn", "unterwegs im Auto", "unterwegs im Flugzeug" (by rail, car, plane...)

The same could be said for "on the way on the street". if there is any redundancy in those 2 equivalent expressions ("on the way on the street" and "auf der Straße unterwegs"), it is present in both. Are you trying to say there is no redundancy in any of them and the answer is incorrect in that regard? Maybe what the author meant is that it's unusual in English to include "on the way" and location (e.g. on the street) in the same sentence because they are most times redundant.

There is no redundancy because if someone is "on the way" with any sort of transportation but not "on the street", the fact of wearing knives is not apparent to anyone nearby. Invisible/hidden knives would not trigger neighbours calling the police. So "auf der Strasse mit Messern unterwegs" implies that he was wearing knives either in his hands or otherwise in plain sight (belts,..).
